# Xamarin Binding Objective-C - unrecognized selector sent

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin

i'm having trouble binding this protocol method.

```
- (void)onInviteTrying:(long)sessionId;
```

It seems pretty simple, but it looks like my C# method isn't being found. Here is what I have in my ApiDefinition.cs file

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
[Protocol]
[Model]
interface PortSIPEventDelegate {

    [Export ("onInviteTrying:")]
    void onInviteTrying (int sessionId);

    //
    // more stuff here
    //

}

interface IPortSIPEventDelegate {}

//
// more stuff here
//
```

and here is my C# file...

```
public class IOSSIPManager : NSObject, IPortSIPEventDelegate, ISIPClient {
    //
    // more stuff here
    //
    public void onInviteTrying(int sessionId)
        {
            // An invite is first trying.
            this.OnCallStatusChanged(sessionId, CallStatusUpdate.InviteTrying);

            ConnectionStatusManager.Instance.Model.SIPDetailedStatus = "SIP OnInviteTrying";
        }
    }
```

I get the following error

Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[StreetSupervisorIOS_IOSSIPManager onInviteTrying:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17011e50

Any idea what I did wrong? My other methods work fine.  Maybe there is a problem binding longs?  I tried with longs and IntPtrs instead of ints, but it didn't work.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: why  do you have 'void' even when you are calling the function?

Comment: I'm never calling the function myself.  I set the delegate of the sipSDK to this, and the system calls the methods when events happen.

Comment: I got the answer.  I have to use [Export ("onInviteTrying:")] above the method in my implementation class since it is an option method.  I also had to clean my whole solution for whatever reason.